# How do you run a rails rake task from heroku CLI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-cli

I have a task called extract. According to [this](https://albertogrespan.com/blog/heroku-scheduler-and-rails-rake-tasks/) blog post, all I'd need do to run the task manually (from the console) is:

```
heroku run rake extract:start
```

But I get the following error:

NameError (undefined local variable or method `extract' for main:Object)

I have also tried: `heroku run rake extract` as per instructions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler), but get the same error

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, you have to run it from your terminal, not the heroku rails console (obvious now I think about it)

Comment: Please add the code for your rake task.

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but to answer it:

```bash
heroku run rails db:migrate
```

(or for older rails versions):

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

In Heroku, there is ability to run console for an app. There you could run `heroku run bash` and do whatever you need in bash env of your server.